# Read data from 3 different files and use one piece of data to search for another within all files

Tags: python

I have three different files from which to read text. Each file contains two different data points.

For example, the first file contains names and phone numbers, the second file contains names and socials, the third file contains socials and incomes.

I want a user to be able to input a phone number and for the program to be able to spit out all other data known about the person associated with that number (i.e. social, name, income).

I have input the files and created 4 different lists and my idea was then to tell the program something like, "if phone number in 'phone' list, grab corresponding indexed value from next list, and so on with each list." Part of my problem though is that I do not necessarily have a corresponding value in each list for every phone number, so I'm not sure utilizing a list's index is the best way to go because indexed values won't necessarily be paired.

I'm certain there has to be a better way to go about this, but I'm just not sure I know what the tools are to get me there...

This is what I've got so far (I have similar code blocks for data2 and data3 but did not include for brevity's sake):

```
data1 = open("data1.txt", "r")
data2 = open("data2.txt", "r")
data3 = open("data3.txt", "r")

names = []
phones = []
socials = []
incomes = []

for line in data1: 
    if "," in line:
        parts = line.split(",")
        name = parts[0]
        if name in names:
            names = names
        else:
            name = name.strip()
            names.append(name)
        phone = parts[1]
        phone = phone.strip()
        phones.append(phone)
```

Comment: can you also please update the file formats and the final output format you are looking for?

Comment: Would all the files fit in memory? If so you can use dict to hold the values, or else you will need something more sophisticated. I think this would be doable with pandas

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this can be solved. This example is neither performant, nor scalable, as it does not use any indexing for the lookup, it just iterates over all the entries in order to find a matching one.

If you want this "procedure" to be performant, I suggest to look into using a database.

```py
# A method for loading the file, which accepts a list of "headers" (or keys) 
# to be used in order to understand what data is in each file. 
# It collects all the data in the entries.
def load_file(entries, filename, keys):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            # clean up and split by comma
            values = line.strip().split(',')
            # transform values into [("name", "a name"), ("phone", "11111111")]
            pairs = zip(keys, values)
            # transform pairs into {"name": "a name", "phone": "11111111"}
            entry = dict(pairs)
            update_or_insert(entries, entry)

def update_or_insert(entries, new_entry):
    # go through all entries
    for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
        # we need to check for matching values of each key of new_entry
        # so iterate through the items of new_entry
        for key, value in new_entry.items():
            # if a key of new_entry exists in an already existing entry
            # and their values are equal
            if key in entry and entry[key] == value:
                # merge entry and new_entry
                new_entry = {**entry, **new_entry}
                # update entry with the new merged one
                entries[index] = new_entry
                # exit the search
                return
    # if no matching values for new_entry keys were found,
    # then insert new_entry into entries
    entries.append(new_entry)

def retrieve(entries, key, value):
    for entry in entries:
        if key in entry and entry[key] == value:
            return entry

entries = []
load_file(entries, "data1.txt", ["name", "phone"])
load_file(entries, "data2.txt", ["name", "social"])
load_file(entries, "data3.txt", ["social", "income"])

print(entries)
print(retrieve(entries, "income", "2000"))
print(retrieve(entries, "name", "a name"))
print(retrieve(entries, "social", "non existent"))
```